# From timestamp to date in Java

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp

I've a problem creating new date in Java. I receive from webservice a timestamp (for example 1397692800). You can see from [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) online converter that is equal to 17 Apr 2014.
When I try to create a new date with this timestamp in Java

```
Date date = new Date (1397692800);
```

console says to me that is equal to Sat Jan 17 05:14:52 CET 1970. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Date(long)` constructor takes the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch. I strongly suspect that you've been given the number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch - so just multiply that value by 1000L.

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000L);
```

Make sure you use 1000L rather than 1000, as otherwise if `timestamp` is an `int`, it will perform the arithmetic in 32 bits instead of 64, and you're very likely to get the wrong results.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't know and now everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_397_692_800L ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2014-04-17T00:00:00Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).